# Inventory Details Subrecord from Client script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Is there any way to get and set serials to the inventory details in client script?
My logic is that I have a text area field, I want to set there serials and then on field change I want to set the serials into the inventory details

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */

define([], function () {


    function fieldChanged(context) {

        var currRec = context.currentRecord;
        var sublistName = context.sublistId;
        var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;
        var line = context.line;

        if (sublistName === 'item' && sublistFieldName === 'custcol3') {

            var testSerials = currRec.getSublistValue('item', 'custcol3', line);
            testSerials = testSerials.split('\u0005');
            console.log(testSerials);

            var qty = testSerials.length;

            currRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'quantity',
                value: qty,
                ignoreFieldChange: true,
                forceSyncSourcing: true
            });

            var invDet = currRec.getSublistSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail', line);

            for (var i = 0; i < testSerials.length; i++) {
                invDet.setSublistValue('inventoryassignment', 'receiptinventorynumber', i, testSerials[i]);
                invDet.setSublistValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        fieldChanged: fieldChanged,
    }
});
```

The error that I get is 'currRec.getSublistSubrecord is not a function'

Answer (score 0):

In a client script you will generally be dealing with `currRec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord`

e.g.

```
require(['N/currentRecord', 'N/record'], function(currRec, record) {
    var rec = currRec.get();
    rec.selectLine({
        sublistId: 'inventory',
        line: 1
    });
    var detail = rec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
        sublistId: 'inventory',
        fieldId: 'inventorydetail'
    });
    if(!detail) {
        console.log('no current detail');
        detail = record.create({type:'inventorydetail', isDynamic:true, defaultvalues:{
            item: rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId:'inventory', 
                fieldId:'item'
            })}});
        rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId:'inventory', 
            fieldId:'inventorydetail',
            value:detail
        });
    }
    console.log(detail.getValue({
        fieldId: 'item'
    }));
    detail.selectNewLine({sublistId:'inventoryassignment'});
    detail.setCurrentSublistText({
        sublistId:'inventoryassignment',
        fieldId: 'binnumber',
        value:'A-22'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats not work. NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_CURRENT_SUBRECORD Not supported on current subrecord: CurrentSubrecord.selectNewLine.

Comment: The sample is fairly old or it may be that lines cannot be added on the record type you are on. When I've done this in a server side script I had to iterate over the available subrecords by some key (e.g. bin or inventory number)